# парсер по нескольким парамметрам в html через selenium

Tags: python, selenium

есть вот такой пример

```
<div jsname="random" jscontroller="random" jsaction="random" aria-label="text">...</div>
<div jsname="random" jscontroller="random" jsaction="random" aria-label="text" class="random" jsshadow="random">...</div>
<div aria-label="text" class="random" jsshadow="random">...</div>
```

Результат должен быть найден только второй `div`, то есть чтобы учло все парамметры.

Я использую `selenium` для парсинга. А именно через `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[]')`. Как правильно это записать? ведь если через запятую, то это же применяет парамметр ИЛИ, а не И.

**UPD:**
Перепробовав разные варианты,стал искать другое решение. Пошел путем поиска по одному тегу, но которые встречается наименьше раз `jsshadow`. Поймал законочерность при разных запросах, что их всего 5 штук. Начал пробовать этот вариант в питоне. Вроде бы подходит, так как он еще постояно последний.

пример:

```
lis = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[jsshadow]')
#дальнейшее применение (их почему-то всего 4, а не 5 (наверно минус скрипт))
list = lis[3].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
```

Comment: `driver.page_source` а дальше `bs4` будет все гораздо проще. (если только кликать по элементам не нужно) Если дадите ссылку на страницу можно будет накидать рабочий вариант

Comment: А вообще `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'random')` должно сработать если элементы класса random не встречаются до искомого элемента

Comment: @Namerek `random` - это я имел ввиду что там рандомное значение/имя

Comment: @Namerek Ну когда я уже попадаю на основную страницу результатов, то там уже клацать не надо а спарсить лишь первую страницу, а именно первая строка справа от главного изображения (они среднего размера) `https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FQfRsM3L.png`

Comment: А информация какая оттуда нужна? Картинки? Ссылки? Что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить нужный элемент так:

```
div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[jsname='random'][class='random']")
```

или так

```
div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@jsname='random' and @class='random']")
```

Я воспользовался ответом  [cruisepandey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644305/selenium-multiple-values-for-find-elements)

Коррекция ответа.

У меня сработало простое перечисление атрибутов в квадратных скобках.

```
div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[jsname][jscontroller][jsaction][class][jsshadow]")
```

Comment: Я не просто так указал что в переменных может быть рандомный текст, при каждом запросе разного изображения, ваш метод не подходит. Мне нужно решение без указания чему раняются перменные. Я попытался без указания, а чисто перечислил их, но ничего так не находит

Comment: @T800 Я скорректировал ответ.

Comment: хмм.. странно, я так пробовал и не сработало. Ладно. Благодарю